# Calculating average of sequential numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create sequential numbers and when the user inputs "0", it should stop and keep the numbers in the memory and then ask the user whether to show the total of these numbers or show the average. The total looks good but when I choose average my console is not responding, it crashes.

```
using System;

class ETA11
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        ETA11_3();
        return 0;
    }
    public static void ETA11_3()
    {
        int number = 0, total = 0, option = 0, counter = 0, average = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input a number (zero for stop): ");
            number = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            total += number;

            if (number == 0) break;
        } while (option != 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Choose an option: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Total");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Average");
        counter++;
        option = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (option)

        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total / number);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger and step through your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you choose option 2, you are dividing 0

```
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total / number);
```

I believe you wanted to divide by `counter`

```
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total / (decimal) counter);
```

however, you need to put `counter++` inside your whileloop too

Comment: yes you are right but the result of average appear as in whole without decimals. for example 5 + 2 = 2,5(average) and it display 25

Comment: in C#, integer divide integer yeild integer 
you need to cast your `counter` to decimal if you want the result in decimal

Answer (score 0):

As Neverever mentioned, you were dividing by number which was 0 causing a `DividedByZeroException`. I also incorporated the correct counter into your loop and cleaned up your do {} while() loop (which was being used incorrectly).

Here is the corrected method:

```
public static void ETA11_3()
{
    int number = 0, total = 0, option = 0;
    double counter = 0d;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input a number (zero for stop): ");
        number = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        total += number;

        if (number == 0) break;
        counter++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Choose an option: ");
    Console.WriteLine("1 - Total");
    Console.WriteLine("2 - Average");
    option = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total);
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total / counter);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh.. I have so far is that I see i just can use "do while" and not single "while"...sorry

Comment: Was that a question @Dimitri?